# Weird margin under body-element on website when viewed with Firefox 7

Tags: html, css, firefox7

My website that I'm currently working on have a problem in Firefox 7. A margin pushes the gradient in #wrapper up from the bottom and ruins the flow. I've reset the margin to 0 on body and html already and can't seem to find anything to explain this. Firebug tells me nothing of value on this case.

My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/1XNLmAE2) and you can look at the website yourself [here](http://pastehtml.com/view/bbqaq5ch3.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the body height to 100%. This might help.
And also add `background-attachment:fixed;` to avoid the background scrolling just in case your page scrolling.

Comment: Added both to body and the gradient goes all the way down. But, `background-attachment: fixed;` didn't solve the scrolling problem.

Comment: Added `overflow: hidden;` to body and problem is solved. Marking your answer as accepted answer.

Comment: Be careful because Adding overflow: hidden; makes page not scrolling if your content is longer then page height and there is a chance in smaller screens like laptops or ipads people see just half of your page.

Comment: The page I'm making will only be used as a portal and no other content will be added. But, if the screen is very smaller, problems arise.